# How do I display errors on login modal form when a user enters invalid credentials in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, laravel-5.6, laravel-authentication

In Laravel 5.6 I am using it's default authentication feature. However I have implemented a modal to replace the default login form. I am trying to keep a login modal form open and display errors upon failed login attempt. My login modal form looks like this:

```
<!-- Modal HTML Markup -->
<div id="login-modal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    <h1 class="modal-title">Login</h1>
   </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="cs-login-form">
      <form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
       <div class="input-holder">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email" class="control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
          <div>
           <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" autofocus>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-holder">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
         <div>
         <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
         </div>
        </div>

       </div>


       <div class="form-group">
       <div>
        <div class="checkbox">
         <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
         </label>
        </div>
       </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          Login
         </button>
         <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">
          Forgot Your Password?
         </a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>    
    </div>
   </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 </div>
```

Currently when a user enters invalid credentials the modal disappears and the user is redirected back to the home page with no errors. My login controller has not been altered and it looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can submit your credentials using an ajax call, then inside your success method, you can check whether it's successful or not & show error if not ok. If it's ok, you can hide modal manually & redirect user to home page.

Comment: check GaimZz's answer

Answer (score 0):

You would need to setup a function manually as [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authenticating-users) explains. You will also need a route and an ajax request to make the login.

Custom Login route:

```
Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@authenticate');
```

In your view you will first need to setup a meta tag with the csrf token to protect yourself from attacks:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then in your ajax you could do this:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/login',
    data: [email: '', password: ''],
    success: function(controllerResponse) {
        if (!controllerResponse) {
           // here show a hidden field inside your modal by setting his visibility 
        } else {
           // controller return was true so you can redirect or do whatever you wish to do here
        }
    }
});
```

Custom controller method could be something like this:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

***Important note**: Please note that I haven't fully coded evrything since stackoverflow is about solving problems not coding for others, so you will need to figure out how to select form data with js, and create the error msg and show it when controller returns false.

Also the controller is really basic, you can improve it with features such as controlling max-login attemps from a certain user, etc..*

Answer (score -1):

You can use session variable $_SESSION['error']. And write a if condition over your login form like

*if(isset($_SESSION['error']) echo "Your error message.")*

And just unset the session variable just after that

Comment: laravels SESSION isn't accessed like that, you can learn about it here on laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#retrieving-data

Comment: I explained it using simple php you can simply implement that in Laravel

Comment: MM question is about laravel so that doesn't make a lot of sense, the least you could do is warn with something like: Attention my answer won't work with laravel I did it with php to explain myself you should change it and use laravel way of accessing the SESSION...

Comment: Plus he doesn't want to redirect that's the point of doing it with AJAX so using SESSION doesn't make a lot of sense